# Adding quotation marks to columns

Tags: sql-server, excel, bcp

**Using:** BCP - stored procedure -  SQL Server 2012 Management Studio

**Issue:** CSV file created by BCP does not add quotes so 1-7 becomes 1st July in Excel.

**Intermediary fix:** By adding `QuoteName` to the fieldname as it was created this adds "[" and "]" to the text and so it exports as "[1-7]" which works however I would prefer not to have the "[]" part and would prefer to have ="columnvalue" instead.

Is there a way to do this, I am trying to avoid adding column names into the select for the BCP to keep it dynamic as reports are ever changing and I was to build it up to allow the client to create their own reports.

**Code:**

```
USE [DATABASE]
GO

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[spPropertyListBCP]
(
    @tableName sysname 
)
AS
BEGIN

DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX)

SET @sql = 
'SELECT p.UPRN AS pUPRN 
 QUOTENAME(p.BuildingNo) As BuildingNo, p.Street 
INTO ' + QUOTENAME(@tableName)  + ' 
FROM TblProperty As p
LEFT JOIN
TblOne As a 
ON p.UPRN = a.UPRN
GROUP BY p.UPRN, p.BuildingNo, p.Street'

EXEC (@sql)

declare @sql1 varchar(8000)

select @sql1 = 'bcp DATABASE.dbo.' + @tableName + ' out C:\Sites\Reports\'+  @tableName + '.csv -c -t, -T -S '+ @@servername

exec master..xp_cmdshell @sql1

END
```

--http://www.excel-sql-server.com/sql-server-export-to-excel-using-bcp-sqlcmd-csv.htm

Comment: Quotes won't help you. Nothing says that "1-7" or "1/7" aren't dates. They are simply quoted fields in the CSV that can contain anything. You have to tell Excel what the field types are. If you simply double click on a CSV, Excel will try to *import* it using defaults and inference from the first few rows. When you *open* a CSV on the other hand, Excel will show a dialog where you can define columns, types etc

Comment: If you really want to export to Excel, why don't you use SSIS, directly or through the Export Data task in SSMS? These will create real Excel files and allow you to specify field types etc before exporting

Comment: When I used to add line by line (slow and painful BCP to the rescue) I added and equals symbol then the quotes around it. The reports are dynamic so the user will request what goes into the report, the example is static. So would SSMS etc.. offer that automation level?

Comment: The way to make Excel treat a field as text is to add a backtick ( ` ).  `Reports` and `user requested` though means that bcp is the *wrong tool* for this job. If you want to create an Excel file from code, use a library like EPPlus to create real Excel files. Or create actual reports with Reporting Services. `bcp` is meant to import/export data, not format it.